# Max subarray - get output formatted correctly

Tags: ruby, algorithm, computer-science, arrays

I am trying out the classic max subarray problem. I am outputting the correct arrays but I want it to be formatted differently. Here is my code:

```
def max_subarray(input)
  return input if input.length == 1

  max = 0
  subarrays = []

  input.each do |element|
    current_subarray = []
    if max + element > element
      current_subarray << subarrays[-1]
      current_subarray << element
      subarrays << current_subarray
      max += element
    else
      subarrays << [element]
      max = element
    end
  end

  subarrays.each do |s|
    print s
    puts ''
  end
end

max_subarray([-2, -3, 4, -1, -2, 1, 5, -3])
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
[-2]
[-3]
[4]
[[4], -1]
[[[4], -1], -2]
[[[[4], -1], -2], 1]
[[[[[4], -1], -2], 1], 5]
[[[[[[4], -1], -2], 1], 5], -3]
```

While these are the numbers that I want I want them to be one array for each line. Not nested arrays. Any ideas?

Thank you,

p.s. once I get this part down it is a small step to find the one with the max sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting your question, but you may be looking for `flatten`.

```
...
subarrays.each do |s|
  print s.flatten
  puts ''
end
...
```

Which results in:

```
(nick@monster)-(~/Desktop)
(504)⚡️ ruby derp.rb 
[-2]
[-3]
[4]
[4, -1]
[4, -1, -2]
[4, -1, -2, 1]
[4, -1, -2, 1, 5]
[4, -1, -2, 1, 5, -3]
```

Comment: Yes that is perfect. Thank you! Why did it nest them to begin with?

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realize it wasn't supposed to in the first place.  Look at your line here: `current_subarray << subarrays[-1]`.  You're inserting an array into the existing array.  If you just wanted to merge them, you'd change it to: `current_subarray += subarrays[-1]`.  You could also use the `concat` method, same thing.  Then you can avoid the `flatten` call completely, though it's nice insurance. :)